# Java Apache POI: create excel with cell values auto typed

Tags: java, types, apache-poi

Is there any functionality to auto fill the data in the cells with the correct type? Now I have to manually set the types, f.e. String or Integer.

Code now is:

```
for (String colName : headerNames) {
    dataRow.createCell(colIndex++).setCellValue(rs.getString(colName));
}
```

At this moment I have to declare for each cell separately what type to use with `rs.getString(colName)`. As the data contains both `Strings` as `Integers`, it would be handy if they could me automatically typed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality inside POI and it would be hard to provide one for Dates as there are a myriad of different date formats in use, but it should be fairly easy to come up with a helper method that you can use in your project, e.g. something like

```
public static void setCellValue(Cell cell, String value) {
    try {
        cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(value));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // not a number, let's use String
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
}
```

This can easily be extended to a date-format as well if you know the actual format that the date is coming in.

Comment: Well, I wrote myself a solution. I created a new array which holds the fields which are Integers, and do a check if the column name is in that array. It would be handy if there was a functionality for automatically assigning the type, so I gave it a try and asked :-)

Comment: Please report an enhancement request at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/ if you have an idea how a fairly performant general functionality could look like!